# Call component's method from main

Tags: vue.js

I need to call a method in a component from outside of Vue app. I defined method send in main.ts file. I am not sure how to get reference to App component so I can pass the message there.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let win = window as any;

win.player = new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),

  methods: {
    send(data: string) {
      // I need to get App reference here
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tie the `Vue` instance to a `const` and call it from outside of the instance by accessing the methods within the instance as if it's a "regular" object:

[[CodePen Mirror]](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/QRRXyR?editors=1010)

```js
// INSIDE OF OUR VUE INSTANCE
const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    alertClickHandler(message) {
      alert(message)
    }
  }
})

// OUTSIDE OF OUR VUE INSTANCE
function outsideVueClick(message) {
  vm.alertClickHandler(message);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<p>Click each button</p>

<!-- OUTSIDE OF OUR VUE INSTANCE -->
<button onclick="outsideVueClick('OUTSIDE VUE')">I am OUTSIDE of Vue</button>

<!-- INSIDE OF OUR VUE INSTANCE -->
<div id="app">
  <br/>
  <button @click="alertClickHandler('INSIDE VUE')">I am INSIDE of Vue</button>
</div>
```